# numbers which are not obtained by the given equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have an equation :

$y = 10a+11b+12c$

Here **atleast two** of coffecients $a,b,c$ are >=1, the others can be 0.
For example: $ a= 1, b= 1, c= 0 $ so $y$ becomes 21.

What are **set of natural numbers which can't be otained by this equation**.

Some of them are: $ \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14..\}$

But I need to count total no of such elements all.

Can I generalize it for n consecutive natural numbers.

Comment: Without the "at least two" part, this is about the Frobenius number, which is a pretty hard problem by itself (once $n>2$, that is). Added conditions don't make it any simpler, I guess.

Comment: That's just a particular case. Well, it could have been simpler than the general case, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well clearly no number less than $21$ is possible.

But $21,22$ and $23$ are possible by $10 + 11, 10+12, 11+12$.

If $n = 10a + 11b + 12c$ is possible then $n+10, n+11$ and $n+12 $are possible by just adding one more of the appropriate numbers.

So $31,32,33,34,35$ are possible, as are $41,42,43,44,45,46,47$ and $51..59$. And $61-71$ are then possible and from there we can get all possible numbers inductively by adding $10, 11$ or $12$.

So we just need to check $24-30$ and $36-40$ and $48-50$ and $60$.

Now: for $2*12 \le 24... 29< 30=3*10$ we can only have at most two values, but they must both be at least $12$ and they can't both be the same so $24... 29$ is impossible.  Likewise $30$ can't be done with only $2$ values and it can't be done with more than $3$ and with $3$ all the values would have to bee $10 $. So $30$ is  also impossible.

$3*12\le 36..40\le 4*10$.  So to get $36... 40$ if we use $3$  or fewer values they must be at least $12$ and if we use $4$ they must be at most $10$ so those are impossible.

And so on:

$4*12 \le 48...50 \le 5*10$ so $48..50$ are impossible as that would require at least $4$ values worth at least $12$ or at most $5$ values worth at most $10$.

And $5*12 = 60 = 6*10$ would require at least $5$ values worth at least $12$ or at most $6$ values worth at most $10$

So That's it.

$\{1...., 21,24...,30,36...40,48,49,50, 60\}$ can not be done.  All others can.

====

=== Alternative answer.

the least common multiple of $10$ and $12$ is $60 = 6*10 = 5*12$.

So if we ever have $n=10a + 11b + 12c$ we can do it in alternative as $n=10(a\pm 6) + 11b + 12(c\mp 5)$.  But we can only do that if $a\ge 6$ (and if $a=6$ then $b \ge 1$) of if $c \ge 5$ (and if $c=5$ then $b \ge 1$).  Thus $71 = 6*10+11 = 5*12 +11$ is the smallest number that can be expressed as $n = 10a + 11b + 12c$ in more than one way.

A trick is that by Bezout we can find $j,k,h$ (some will be negative) so $10j + 11k + h = 1$.  Therefore if we can find $n = 10a + 11b + 12c$ we can find $n+1 = 10(a+j) + 11(b+k) + 12(c+h)$.  The only catch is that two of $a+j, b+k, c+h$ must be greater or equal to $1$.

Now obviously $11 - 10 = 1$ and $12-11=1$.

If we have $n=10a+11b + 12c$ we can ge $n+1 = 10(a-1) + 11(b+1) + 12c$.  This requires that $a\ge 1$ and if $a=1$ that $c > 0$.

If we can't do $n+1 = 10(a-1) + 11(b+1)+12c$ we can do $n+1 = 10a + 11(b-1) + 12(c+1)$.  This requires that $b\ge 1$ and if $b=1$ that $a>0$.

So the only way we *can't* go from $n$ to $n+1$ is if $a=0$ and $b=1$.  But if $a=0, b=1$ and $c \ge 5$ we *can* go from $n=10*0 + 11*1 + 10*c$ to $n= 10*6 + 11*1 + 10*(c-1)$ to $n+1 = 10*5 + 11*2 + 10*(c-1)$.

So the numbers we we can acheive but not inductively get the next one are

$n = 10*0 + 11*1 + 12*c$ for $c =1,2,3,4$

The very next lowest number we can achieve is:

$M > n = 10*0 + 11*1 + 12*c = 10*(c+1) + (2c+1)$ where $2c+1 = 3,5,7,9$ is

$M = 10*(c+1) + 11*1 + 12*0$.

So the smallest number we can acheive is:

$n = 10 + 11 = 21$. From there we can inductively get to $n= 10*0 + 11*1 + 12*1= 23$.

The next we can acheive is $n = 10*2 + 11*1= 31$.  From there we can inductively get to $n=10*0+11*1 + 12*2= 35$.

The next we can acheive is $n = 10*3 + 11*1 + 12*0= 41$ and from there we can inductively get to $n = 10*0 + 11*1 + 12*3 = 47$.

The next we can acheive is $n= 10*4 +11*1 + 12*0 = 51$ and from there we can inductively get to $n=10*0 + 11*1 + 4*12=59$.

The next we can acheive is $n=10*5+11*1 + 0=61$ and frome there we can inductively get to $n = 10*0 + 11*1 + 5*12 = 6*10 + 11*1 + 0 = 71$ and from there we can inductively get all higher integers.

Comment: can I generalize it?

Comment: Generalize what?

Comment: No, an explicit algorithm is known for the largest non-possible natural number if you have two terms. However, for three or more terms there is no known formula. But there is an algorithm to compute it if you so choose. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem